# Can e-mails appear to be sent from Marketing Cloud but not actually be sent?

Tags: marketing-cloud

This is probably a very silly question, but doing due diligence.  We have an SFMC subscriber who insists that she is not receiving some, but not all, of our e-mail communications.  SFMC is saying that the e-mails in question were sent.  My boss wants to know if there is any scenario under which SFMC would say that an e-mail was sent, but the e-mail was in fact not sent?

Thanks!

Comment: sent is not delivered, so if its on the _sent dataview SFMC delivered the email to the ESP the ESP could then be holding or trashing the email and not delivering it

Comment: Open a support case, they can help you investigate. @EazyE if the emails were held by the ESP wouldn’t they appear as a blocked bounce?

Comment: @zuzannamj inbox placement is difficult to measure without additional tools (e.g. Return Path). As emails being marked as spam (and placed in spam folder) don’t result in a block bounce.